# How can I make this shape?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the following with HTML and CSS, when I have been provided with background-image.

```
<span class='some-cl'> defence personnel </span>
```

[image]

Comment: you could do it with `background-clip`.(requires CSS3) only because it appears to be 'transparent' (from the image the background doesnt appear to be different). However if you just want the shape, and are re-applying the inside background there are other options. Is it indeed transparent?

Comment: sorry i mean `background-clip-path, however, support is fairly limited: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path . Here is an example of using it to make different shapes: http://codepen.io/Darsain/pen/IqjFe

Answer (score 2):

So a variation of it is possible with CSS, but my version is the ugliest piece of shit you'll find. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/7s4L0jhy/

I have an extra element for the half circle thing, but other than that, it's all variable according to the text in your element.

```
.p {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And then I create the top bar, but leave space for the circle:

```
.p:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: calc(50% + 35px);
    left: -3px;
    height: 3px;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
.p:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% + 35px);
    right: -3px;
    height: 3px;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

And lastly, the fake circle thingy:

```
.p .bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    top: -30px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

As per the other answer, an image would definitely be easier for you, but this should work for anything ie10+. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to solve this. However I think the requirement here is high ***scalability***, that is we can change the size of the outside element (the wrapper) and the shape should keep scaling accordingly. Doing so requires a little trick relating to `overflow:hidden`, the top shape includes a nearly half circle at center and the 2 lines besides, the trick here is we need to fix the ends (of the 2 lines) connecting to the nearly half circle and let the other ends free, so that when scaling up/down the `overflow:hidden` will cut off those ends if there is any error in calculation.

Here is the code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class='frame'>
  <div class='top'>
     <div class='peak'></div>
  </div>    
  <div class='content'>
    Defense personnel
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.frame > .top, .top > .peak {
  position:absolute;
}
.frame {
  position:relative;
}
.frame > .top {
  overflow:hidden;
  left:-3px;
  right:-3px;
  padding-top:100%;
  bottom:100%;
}
.frame > .top:before, .frame > .top:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border-top:3px solid white;    
  width:30%;
  bottom:0;
}
.frame > .top:before {
  right:70%; 
}
.frame > .top:after {
  left:70%;
}
.top > .peak {
  border:3px solid white;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:40%;
  padding-top:40%;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,44%);        
}
.frame {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top:100px;
  border:3px solid white;
  border-top:0;
}
.frame > .content {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:white;
}
body {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600);
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ywdzqL2d/).

Try resizing the `.frame` and you'll see how flexable it is.

Answer (score -1):

```
.some-cl{background:#003 /*bg color*/ url(your_image.jpg) no-repeat 50%; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; padding-top:40px /*adjust at will */ }
```

there are better and more complex methods, but since you're asking extremely basic CSS questions, I assume this should be enough

Comment: and how do i make the tomb thing ?

Comment: you're voting down and asking for help? are you for real?

Comment: I think he wants to make it with CSS-- not an image. And it may or may not have been him who downvoted you.